# Encryption for HTTP Rest Call

Tags: rest-api, integration, encryption

I am trying a simple rest call from one instance of salesforce to another. Server Endpoint URL is on ***https***. I want to confirm, will making such call to ***https*** endpoint alone, encrypt the Endpoint parameters (soql in my case) along with data sent back by server ? Or do I need to implement CA certificates somewhere ?

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://na12.salesforce.com/services/data/v22.0/query/?q=SELECT+id+from+CustomObject+WHERE+name+LIKE+'abc');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug('Response code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
```

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffic would be encrypted, only Salesforce could see the unencrypted data on each end. Also, as a practical matter, internal API calls (between orgs) never leave the Salesforce Data Center, so there wouldn't be any chance for an interloper to see the data anyways.